# Proper use of libvlc_media_open_cb

Tags: libvlc, realbasic, xojo

I'm trying to use the [`libvlc_media_new_callbacks`](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga591c3cbe56444f1949165b2b9b75d8e2) function to play media from memory using libvlc. This function expects pointers to four callback functions: `Open`, `Read`, `Seek`, and `Close`.

```vb
Declare Function libvlc_media_new_callbacks Lib "libvlc.dll" (Instance As Ptr, OpenCB As Ptr, ReadCB As Ptr, SeekCB As Ptr, CloseCB As Ptr, Opaque As Ptr) As Ptr

Dim opaque As Ptr = SomeOpaqueValue()
Dim handle As Ptr = libvlc_media_new_callbacks(instance, AddressOf MediaOpen, AddressOf MediaRead, AddressOf MediaSeek, AddressOf MediaClose, opaque)
```

The `Read`, `Seek`, and `Close` callbacks all work fine if I don't specify an `Open` callback but that means libvlc won't know how long the media is.

When I *do* specify an `Open` callback it gets invoked with the correct `opaque` parameter but the other callbacks get a null pointer instead. This makes it impossible to know which stream the callback should be working on.

Have I misunderstood the purpose of the open callback?

Here are my callback functions:

```vb
Shared Function MediaOpen(Opaque As Ptr, Buffer As Ptr, ByRef BufferSize As UInt64) As UInt32
  Dim r As BinaryStream = Streams.Lookup(Opaque, Nil)
  If r = Nil Then Return 1 ' invalid Opaque

  Buffer = Nil  ' Not sure what to do with this parameter
  BufferSize = r.Length
  Return 0
End Function
```

```vb
Shared Sub MediaClose(Opaque As Ptr)
  If Streams.HasKey(Opaque) Then Streams.Remove(Opaque)
  If Streams.Count = 0 Then Streams = Nil
End Sub
```

```vb
Shared Function MediaRead(Opaque As Ptr, Buffer As Ptr, BufferSize As Integer) As UInt32
  Dim r As BinaryStream = Streams.Lookup(Opaque, Nil)
  If r = Nil Then Return 0 ' invalid Opaque

  Dim mb As MemoryBlock = Buffer
  Dim data As MemoryBlock = r.Read(BufferSize)
  mb.StringValue(0, data.Size) = data
  Return data.Size
End Function
```

```vb
Shared Function MediaSeek(Opaque As Ptr, Offset As UInt64) As Int32
  Dim r As BinaryStream = Streams.Lookup(Opaque, Nil)
  If r = Nil Then Return 1 ' invalid Opaque
  If Offset > r.Length Then Return 1 ' invalid offset

  r.Position = Offset
  Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: Just a guess: Could it be that you need to return a value from Open, and that value will be passed to the other calls instead of the opaque value?

Comment: The documentation says to return zero for success and non-zero otherwise, which I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, you have to allocate a buffer and return its address in the open's Buffer parameter (you need to change it into a ByRef parm for that!). Then you'll get that same buffer ptr passed in the other functions.

Ideally, you'd set

```
Buffer = r
```

in MediaOpen. But Xojo won't let you. Instead, you need to maintain a Dictionary in which you store `r` and then associate that with a value you can assign to the Buffer parm.

Here's an example (not tested):

```
Static Property OpenedBuffers as Dictionary
Static Property OpenedBufferID as Integer

Shared Function MediaOpen(Opaque As Ptr, ByRef HandleOut As Integer, ByRef BufferSize As UInt64) As UInt32
  Dim r As BinaryStream = Streams.Lookup(Opaque, Nil)
  If r = Nil Then Return 1 ' invalid Opaque
  if OpenedBuffers = nil then OpenedBuffers = new Dictionary
  OpenedBufferID = OpenedBufferID + 1
  OpenedBuffers.Value(OpenedBufferID) = r
  HandleOut = OpenedBufferID
  BufferSize = r.Length
  Return 0
End Function

Shared Function MediaRead(Handle As Integer, Buffer As Ptr, BufferSize As Integer) As UInt32
  Dim r As BinaryStream = OpenedBuffers.Value(Handle)
  ...

Shared Sub MediaClose(Handle As Integer)
  Dim r As BinaryStream = OpenedBuffers.Value(Handle)
  OpenedBuffers.Remove (Handle)
  If Streams.HasKey(r) Then Streams.Remove(r)
  ...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'd already set up a Dictionary to associate the `Opaque` value with the correct stream. So basically all I did was copy the `Opaque` parameter into `HandleOut` parameter and it worked!